# Cannot get ntpdate cron to run

Tags: 12.04, server, cron

I'm trying to have a daily cron update the clock on my 12.04 server.  I've followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/NTP.html), but it still doesn't run:  After a few weeks, the clock once again is off by a few seconds.  I've been Googling around for solutions, but nothing seems to help.  From what I've found on Google, I've verified the following:

Running the script manually works fine:

```
root@...:~# /etc/cron.daily/ntpdate
13 May 14:42:22 ntpdate[6927]: adjust time server 96.44.142.5 offset -0.018984 sec
```

The script is executable:

```
root@...:~# ls -l /etc/cron.daily/
total 60
....
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    46 May 12 20:41 ntpdate
....
```

I don't see any cron-related errors in the syslog.

```
May 13 06:25:01 ... CRON[6704]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
```

I've used an absolute path, just in case the cron PATH was missing it:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com pool.ntp.org
```

I've done a dry run:

```
root@...:~# run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily
...
/etc/cron.daily/ntpdate
...
```

I can't see any reason why it wouldn't be working.

Comment: Will you give the output of the command when running it from the console?

Comment: Alright, edited my question to include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you have a shebang "#!/bin/bash" to specify howthe script is to be parsed.

ntpdate script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com pool.ntp.org
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using cron, you could just install `ntp` and let the daemon automatically adjust the clock for you while the server is running.

Comment: Yes, this is better than running a cron. It's also very easy: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html

Comment: But in some cases it doesn't work: for example in virtual machines, even if deamon ntp/ntpd is running, the system clock after weeks can be moved few minutes from the correct time. And in that situations there is need to stop ntpd,run ntpdate, run ntpd.